# How expensive is to use sess.run() in tensorflow?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, machine-learning

I wrote a machine learning algorithm in python using tensorflow. The algorithm pseudo-code can be seen in the figure below. In this algorithm I'm using sess.run() more than one time in the training loops. The reason I have to use more than one sess.run() is because I have to evaluate the same neural network at different inputs to calculate δ. For some reason that I still don't know my code is extremely slow (see [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203201/bipedalwalker-v2-one-step-actor-critic-agent-trains-slow), [ai](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203201/bipedalwalker-v2-one-step-actor-critic-agent-trains-slow) to see the code and related questions).

[image]
 Figure taken from the book [Reinforcement Learning An Introduction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262193981) by Richard S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto.

My questions for this stack are the following:

#### 1) How much more expensive is to do two sess.run() instead of one. For example:

to do,

```
sess.run([op1],feed_dict={input:data})
sess.run([op2],feed_dict={input:data})
```

instead of,

```
sess.run([op1,op2],feed_dict={input:data})
```

is there any difference at all?

#### 2) What can be an efficient way to evaluate the same neural network at different inputs at the same step?

I'm currently calculating δ as follows:

```
self.delta = self.time_step_info['r'] + (not self.time_step_info['d'])*self.gamma*sess.run(self.critic(),feed_dict={self.state_in:self.time_step_info['s1']}) - sess.run(self.critic(),feed_dict={self.state_in:self.time_step_info['s']})
```

Comment: You may compare the computation time using `time.time()`...or if you wanna know exactly the CPU/GPU time of each operation (and whether it is done on CPU or GPU, whether the hardware communication takes most of the time), profile `sess.run` by feeding `options=tf.RunOptions(...)`. Multiple `sess.run` are valid when you update the model after each run. Otherwise, a single run is better because each `sess.run` recalculates every node in the graph. However, your hardware may limit how large the inputs could be.

Answer (score 0):

For your firsst question, I'm not sure.

But for your second question, as you may already know, the input should be a matrix. A matrix can contain multiple `X`. And NN will generate a corresponding result matrix `Y`, each line of this matrix `Y` is the output of line in `X`.